# Hedera and Hashpack Transfer Transaction - Need Seller/Buyer Signatures

Tags: decentralized-applications, hedera-hashgraph, hashpack

Hi I'm working on a dapp targeting the Hedera network using Hashpack.

When I'm trying to do a transfer transaction, I need both signatures from the seller and buyer.

I have read some docs but I'm not sure the best approach here.

What is the best way to get both signatures if both people are not going to be present at the same time? Is there something my dapp can use to achieve this or do I have to code it myself?

Any ideas would be great, TIA.